# React App running fine on localhost but not able to fetch static files like main.chunk.js, bundle.js and 0.chunk.js etc

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nginx, static, web-deployment

The Application is running fine on localhost but when the react app development server is hosted on production with a public Ip and accessed using that public Ip the page is not able to fetch static files like favicon, main.chunk.js, bundle.js, and 0.chunk.js, etc. I am proxying react app development server with Nginx using a route /rx on this production server. I had begun this project using create-react-app. It was working fine till now but suddenly this problem has popped up and even reverting the commits to earlier stable ones is not helping.

My **index.js** looks like this

[image]

This is how my **package.json** looks like

[image]

This is how my **app.js** looks

[image]

**Here are the error Screen Shots when accessed over public ip**

[image]

However everything is working fine when same code is accessed over localhost as seen follows.

[image]